# Why is Boole's inequality useful?

Tags: probability-theory

I know this is trivial question, but could anyone give me a brief explanation how this helped in Probability Theory.

Comment: Analysis of randomized algorithms is one specific scenario where I have seen Boole's inequality (and also other tail bounds) being put to great use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the union of a collection of events. We want non-trivial bounds on the probability of this union event. Using the properties of any measure, the sum of the probabilities of the events is an upper bound. This is best possible if the events are disjoint. The more probability of intersection of the events, the less good is the upper bound.